# Stored procedure adds time to date format

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I am using SQL server and stored procedures and I want to do a simple SELECT.

In my table I have a DATE format, which shows correctly in the database as yy-mm-dd.
When I call the stored procedure in my C# app, I also get a time value for every row (11/14/1987 12:00:00 AM).

How can I remove the time format?

Here is my select stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Employee_GetAllEmployees]
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM 
    dbo.Employee
END
```

Comment: What format do you want ? Edit the question.

Comment: I want date format. No time

Comment: Where do you want to format the dateTime? Will you only ever want the sproc to return a date (no time) or will that dateTime be used elsewhere and need the time part?

Comment: I want the sproc to return a date (no time)

Answer (score 0):

If you want only `date` then use `convert()` :

```
SELECT emp.*, CONVERT(DATE, date_col) AS New_date
FROM dbo.Employee emp;
```

Comment: @alexxa. . . `emp` is table alias which is valid across in ALL dbms.

Comment: ty, but unfortunately the result is the same :(..I still get the time

Comment: @alexxa. . . You need to use `new_date` column, not old one.

Comment: yes. I did that. I will try again. Thx for the patience

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server `date` data type [maps to .NET `DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data), which includes a time component. For formatting purposes in your application, use `ToString` according to your desired display format.

```
var formattedDateString = dateTypeField.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Although you can format the value in T-SQL and return a string instead, burdening the database server for presentation formatting limits performance and scalability and is not considered a best practice.